# "as great as has"

Tags: phrases, adverbs, present-perfect, present-tense

Which sentence is more correct and why?

Einstein is as great a scientest as HAS ever lived.

Or,

Einstein is as great a scientist as ever lived.

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Einstein is as great a scientist as has ever lived.

This sentence is grammatically correct, although the wording is something you would expect from an academic paper. If you said this in casual conversation, it would sound a bit strange. For that purpose, something like the following would be preferred:

> Einstein was one of the greatest scientists to ever live.

---

> Einstein is as great a scientist as ever lived.

This sentence is not correct. The difference is this: The "has" causes the sentence to be in the "present perfect" tense. This means that although the action (living) occurred in the past, the meaning of the statement matters right now. Even though Einstein lived in the past, the sentence is not saying that he *was* a great scientist when he lived, but he is no longer one of the greatest now that he is dead. The sentence is saying that even though he lived in the past, he is still one of the greatest. It is the "has" that makes that distinction, not the "is" after Einstein.

On a semi-related note, you should usually use "was" instead of "is" when you are talking about someone who has already died. As I mentioned above, changing "is" to "was" does not mean that Einstein is no longer considered a great scientist; it simply means that he is not a scientist anymore, because he is not alive anymore. Since you had "is" in your original sentence, it might be difficult to see the difference between a sentence with "has" and a sentence without it. However, if you use "was", the difference is much more apparent:

> Einstein was as great a scientist as ever lived.

This sentence basically says that when Einstein was alive, he was as great as any scientist who had lived up until then.

> Einstein was as great a scientist as has ever lived.

This sentence basically says that when Einstein was alive, he was as great as any scientist who has lived prior to 2018 (or whatever the current date is).